# Problem with Dock on MacOS at wxPython application

Tags: python, macos, wxpython, wxwidgets

There is a problem with dock on MacOS.
In context menu at dock-icon there are 2 items: Standart Quit of MacOS and some menu item Quit, that i didn't add.
That Quit, that not mine, is works and associated with my method:

```
class TrayIcon(wx.TaskBarIcon):
    def make_menu(self):
        self.menu = wx.Menu()
        item = self.menu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT,"Exit", "Exit from application")
        self.menu.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.on_menu_exit, item)

    def CreatePopupMenu(self):
        self.make_menu()
        return self.menu
```

As you see, i сall it "Exit", but i see "Quit", but it still handles by my method.

And Quit that is system, it won't work, when i select it, nothing happens, but next actions with application lead to this error message:

> File
>   "/var/tmp/wxWidgets/wxWidgets-13~231/2.6/DSTROOT/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/wx-2.8-mac-unicode/wx/_core.py",
>   line 14501, in **getattr** wx._core.PyDeadObjectError: The C++ part of
>   the Main object has been deleted, attribute access no longer allowed.

What did I do wrong?
Thanks

Comment: You're using the stock id wx.ID_EXIT (see http://wiki.wxpython.org/SpecialIDs) so wxPython is changing the label of the menu item. You didn't show all the code, so I'm not sure what happens in `self.on_menu_exit`. You may want to add that method to your question.

Comment: there are nothing intresting, just > print "Quit clicked"

Comment: And problem not here, problem is that on_menu_exit is not called!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause is probably that your are not keeping a reference to `item`. It is bound in `self.menu.Bind`, but you do not keep a reference in the Python code. So the Python garbage collector sees this `wx.MenuItem` that isn't referenced anymore (within the Python code), so it is deleted. Wx's clean up code (`__del__`) is called and the object is also removed in the C++ code, *although it is still in use!*. So when you click the menu item, it tries to match the clicked menu item with the (by then) removed menu item and it throws the aforementioned `PyDeadObjectError`. To work around this 'bug', simply keep a reference to the `wx.MenuItem`:

```
self.item = self.menu.Append(...
```